# Regex to match specific words in java

Tags: java, regex

E.g. Any combination of these 3 words [AB,CD,EF] should pass the regex. Also, it should not allow duplicates.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by combination? `"ABEFCD"`?

Comment: like "AB,CD,EF", "AB,CD", "AB,EF" etc

Comment: this site (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) may help you

Comment: This is not a good fit for regexes. It is possible, but very cumbersome. Why does it have to be a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend a regex for this. But it is possible:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches(
    "(?x)                  # Verbose regex:\n" +
    "(?!.*(AB|CD|EF).*\\1) # Make sure there are no dupes in the string\n" +
    "\\s*                  # Match optional whitespace.\n" +
    "(?:AB|CD|EF)          # Match one of the three candidates\n" +
    "(?:                   # Try to match...\n" +
    " \\s*,\\s*            #  a comma, optionally surrounded by whitespace\n" +
    " (?:AB|CD|EF)         #  followed by one of the candidates\n" +
    ")*                    # zero or more times\n" +
    "\\s*                  # Match optional whitespace.");
```

Comment: A shorter way of looking for duplicates is `(?!.*(AB|CD|EF).*\\1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...as I am very new to regex I asked this question on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious solution is just to enumerate all 15 possibilities in a regex -- with a little work, you can probably factor out some terms and get a slightly more compact regex -- but there's not going to be another way to express those constraints in a regular expression.

Comment: Yes there is. Although it's not pretty :)

Comment: ...Okay, I admit that you're right, but I'm weeping at my keyboard that that monstrosity exists...and I still think that the direct "enumerate all possibilities" solution is _shorter._

Comment: You can't say I didn't warn you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

"No duplicates" means counting.  Regular expressions in general cannot do that, so it is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Did you see my solution? "No duplicates" means "counting to 1", and regexes can do that just fine.

Comment: Regular expressions in general cannot do `\1`.

Comment: First, this question was tagged "java regex", and Java, like nearly every other regex engine in the real world, certainly can do backreferences. Of course, in ivory-tower theoretical informatics, a strict definition of "regular" expressions prohibits the use of backreferences. But everybody else is quite happy to extend the meaning of "regular expression" to something that is actually useful in practice.